# Pip verify packet integrity

Tags: hash, pgp, python

I've recently used `pip` to install packets inside of a public network without thinking about it:

```
pip install packetname
```

and I was wondering if pip does some sort of verification via hashing or PGP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from SSL based security aspect, when installing from PyPI `pip` has an [MD5 based checking mechanism](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#hashes-from-pypi) (though the hashing algorithm can be changed), which is designed to prevent/check download corruptions and not really be a security guard:

> PyPI provides an MD5 hash in the fragment portion of each package
>   download URL, like #md5=123..., which pip checks as a protection
>   against download corruption. Other hash algorithms that have
>   guaranteed support from hashlib are also supported here: sha1, sha224,
>   sha384, sha256, and sha512. Since this hash originates remotely, it is
>   not a useful guard against tampering and thus does not satisfy the
>   --require-hashes demand that every package have a local hash.

But, `pip` can also work in the [hash-checking mode](https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#hash-checking-mode) (which is not enabled by default), which allows you to validate against local hashes for each of the packages you install:

> Since version 8.0, pip can check downloaded package archives against
>   local hashes to protect against remote tampering.

Check out this relevant thread as well:

- [Which security measures does PyPI and similar third-party software repositories take?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/79326/58553)

Comment: @AntonAlthoff since the md5 hash is also coming from the PyPI server, you cannot trust it either..

Answer (score 0):

pip uses https as transfer protocol unless you consciously circumvent this. This already includes some verification (the package comes from a trusted source and is transferred in encrypted form and only decrypted on the target computer).

I am not sure about additional verification mechanisms built into pip; but there probably are.