# Does Firefox's addon/extension installer provide cryptographic authentication and integrity validation?

Tags: authentication, firefox, integrity, package-manager

Does Firefox's built-in installer for addons/extensions validate its payload's authentication and integrity for all files it downloads before actually installing them?

I avoid in-app updates because, more often than not, developers do not take the time to properly implement authentication checks when downloading files from the Internet. Sometimes they do integrity checks, but when the checksum/hashes are downloaded from the same location as the payload, it provides integrity but not authenticity.

Generally, I try to install software from a [package manager that properly authenticates](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/246425/does-apt-get-enforce-cryptographic-authentication-and-integrity-validation-by-de?rq=1) all packages after download and before install, but not all Firefox addons are available from `apt`.

Does Firefox provide cryptographic authentication and integrity checks for all items downloaded before installing them for *all* extensions and add-ons?

> Note: Transport validation via X.509 is nice, but it's *not* an authentication check on software releases because
>
> 1. It does not protect against publishing infrastructure compromise because the private key lives hot on the web server. Historically, [many malicious software releases have been served by web servers](https://github.com/cncf/tag-security/tree/main/supply-chain-security/compromises) with valid https certs.
> 2. X.509 doesn't provide authentication of the actual software publisher because it doesn't pin to their key; it will happily accept any malicious key that's signed by a CA (or its subordinate) in the root store. Historically, [X.509 PKI root stores have had to remove untrustworthy CAs, and it's reasonable to assume that there are untrustworthy CAs in these lists](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/234052/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-all-government-agencies-with-cas-in-pki-root-stores) at any point in time. Also, it's trivial to obtain a valid cert if you compromise DNS or web publishing infrastructure via the [ACME protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Certificate_Management_Environment).
>
> Proper cryptographic authentication checks should defend against release infrastructure compromise, and therefore require payloads to be cryptographically signed by a private key that's stored offline (away from the release web infrastructure) and whose verification is done with a single, pinned public key.

Comment: If you cite something please add the source. And provide context for the citation - right now it is not clear to me why you cite it at all. And if what you marked as citation isn't actually a citation then please don't format is as such to avoid confusion.

Comment: So, like this? https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-on-signing-in-firefox

Comment: this is a good question - firefox likely does do some sort of periodic validation, but i don't know the specifics so i can't answer - one time in recent history [all addons were disabled due to some signing cert expiring](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1548973) (and https://github.com/mozilla/addons/issues/851) - one way to mitigate is to ensure that critical addons' icons are left visible (ie. adjacent to the location bar) instead of buried in the overflow